# wc_create_order making duplicates

Tags: woocommerce

I am writing a batch process to import some orders from a mysql table called tbl_bankimport:

```
$bankrecs = $wpdb->get_results("Select * from tbl_bankimport");

foreach ($bankrecs as $bankrec) {
   $order = wc_create_order(array(['customer_id' => $bankrec->user_id]));
   echo "Order " . $order->id . "created </br>";
}
```

In my test file I have 47 record and when I run this I get 47 order # echoed on the screen.  But I end up with 94 records in woocommerce!

If I clear down the orders replace this:

```
$order = wc_create_order(array(['customer_id' => $bankrec->user_id]));
```

with

```
$order = wc_create_order(array(['customer_id' => 7072]));
```

and then re-run I get 47 records entered.

Bemused and mystified!

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the customer_id from the data array and adding it like this:

update_post_meta($order->id, '_customer_user', bankrecs->user_id );

seems to be a solution.